# VBA Applying formula to range and finding sum of outputs

Tags: vba

Im tring to apply the formula `GammaSingle` to each cell in my range `root` (its range is just 1 column wide), then find the sum of the ouput of all of those cells. Not sure how to go about doing this

```
Public Function PsiFinal(ByVal Variables As Range, ByVal root As Range, ByVal t As Double) As Double

For Each cell In Range

    'something that will apply GammaSingle(Variables, cell.value, t) to each cell in the range
    

PsiFinal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(root)
'PsiFinal would be the sum of all their values after theyve gone through the formula GammaSingle

End Function
```

Comment: What does `GammaSingle` return? i.e. is it `Public Function GammaSingle(...) As Double`?

Comment: @BigBen GammaSingle returns a double

Comment: `Dim tempSum As Double`, `tempSum = tempSum + GammaSingle(Variables, cell.value, t)`?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Public Function PsiFinal(ByVal Variables As Range, _
                         ByVal root As Range, _
                         ByVal t As Double) As Double
    Dim c As Range, rv

    For Each c In root.Cells
        rv = rv + GammaSingle(Variables, c.Value, t)
    Next c 
    PsiFinal = rv    
End Function
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I appreciate the help a lot